# Sripe: Is it a bad practice to create a seeprate connected account for your buisness?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have this marketplace that charges some % comission on the price of the item sold. This commission amount, is the amount that I can 'take home' while the rest I want to keep in my stripe account so the seller can either payout, or use the funds gained from the sale to purchase other things on the marketplace.

So how do I logically seperate commission funds and sale funds? My idea is this

I create a new connected account that links with my bank account. Whenever a sale is made, the commission amount i transfer to the connected account. The rest stays on my main platform account. When the commissions in the connected account accumulate, I do a payout to my bank account.

My question is for anyone who has had experience with stripe, does this make sense? Is it a bad practice?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is about business practice, not programming.

Comment: Sorry about that I guess this wasn't the proper place to ask

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your marketplace is going to have more than one seller on it, you'll likely want to do things the other way around.

You'd use your Stripe account as the Platform Account for the marketplace, and then you would give each seller a Connected Account. This separates your profits, and isolates the funds for each of your sellers.

Each [charge type](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges) that is available for Connect has a mechanism to allow your platform to keep a portion of the sale.

I would also recommend that you contact [Stripe support](https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true) to ensure that allowing your sellers to hold funds in Stripe and then continue spending those funds in your marketplace is a use case that they permit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue is that my platform is in Canada, and a connected account is not viable for a user who wants to be payed out to some place other than canada. When a sale is made, the funds accumulate in sellers account (not on stripe but on the website), but when they withdraw they get the option to withdraw via stripe or payoneer. If the user chooses stripe, then they get a connected account.  So I can't transfer to connected account at the time of sale because seller might not have one.

Comment: This means that funds get accumulated on my platform account and it becomes difficult to keep track which funds platform keeps and which must be reserved for payout. If I have a connected account for collecting platform fees, then everytime a sale is made i can trasnfer the fee portion to the connected account and let the amount to be paid out later accumulate in the platform account. It just kinda seems hacky though because connected accounts seem to be intended for customers. If only you could group funds in stripe.